# Mathematica doesn't give the correct value of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, fourier-analysis

I want to calculate the following integral with Mathamtica

`Integrate[ E^(−2 x I) (Log[Abs[Cos[x − a]]] + Pi I/2 Sign[Cos[x − a]]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`

where $a$ is a real number.  The result should be $\pi e^{-2a \text{i}}$. However, Mathematica gives a result $0$. Then I tried to caculate it with the assumption $a \in \mathbb{R}$,

```
Integrate[E^(-2 x I) (Log[Abs[Cos[x-a]]] + Pi I/2 Sign[Cos[x -a]]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> Elements[a, Reals]]
```

It still gives a result $0$.

Finally, I defined a function

```
f[a_] := Integrate[ E^(−2 x I) (Log[Abs[Cos[x − a]]] + Pi I/2 Sign[Cos[x − a]]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and calculate

```
f[2]
```

Now, it gives the correct answer $\pi e^{-4 i}$.  What's the matter?

I'll add some remark. I'm using v13.3. This integral comes from the fourier transformation of p.v.$\frac{1}{z^2}$. Days ago, when I first calculated this integral, mma gives an answer like Domen commented. But today, it gives a result $0$. Certainly both results are wrong.  As Neumann answered, a simple change of variable solves this problem, and bmf gives another way, but only when we already know mma doesn't work properly as the OP.

Comment: Which version are you using? In v13.3, I get the result `ConditionalExpression[0, 2 a + π < 0 || 2 a > 5 π]` which is undefined for $a=2$. Note that if you are calculating a Fourier transform, you should not be using `Integrate` but [`FourierTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html) because these two do not behave the same way.

Comment: @Domen I got the same result that you got in **v13.2**, however, `f[2]` evaluates!

Comment: Here is a simplification for the **integrand**. Observe that `Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals, 
 Log[Abs[Cos[a - x]]] == Log[Sqrt[Cos[(a - x)]^2]] // FullSimplify]` yields `True`

Comment: Looks like an bug to me. I would report this to "support@wolfram.com"

Comment: @Domen    I'm using v13.3 too. Actually, days ago, I get a similar result as yours. But today, I always get a result zero.  I don't why.  I will try FourierTransform. However, I want to know why Integrate doesn't work.

Comment: @gaoqiang, I would say you might have defined `a` somewhere in the code so that it has a value now. What is the color of `a` inside `Integrate`? Blue or black? It should be blue.

Comment: @Domen No. But the result you get is still wrong.  As Neumann answered, a simple change of variable solves this problem. If I don't know why mma gives a wrong value, I'll be misled by mma next time.

Comment: @gaoqiang, just another comment: You can somehow force Mathematica to get you the correct answer with appropriate [assumptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSN14.png). Also, can you please elaborate a bit more on the Fourier transform? What is the exact function that is being transformed?

Comment: @Domen It's the fourier transform of p.v. 1/z^2  (Cauchy principal value), which is a Calderon-Zygmund kernel.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I managed to make progress --- note that I did not use the analytic result of the OP

```
integrand = 
  E^(-2 x I) (Log[Abs[Cos[x - a]]] + Pi I/2 Sign[Cos[x - a]]);
```

Firstly, I hate `Abs` and I think Mma shares my feelings so I am going to help her out, based on the fact that

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals && a ∈ Reals, 
 Log[Abs[Cos[a - x]]] == Log[Sqrt[Cos[(a - x)]^2]] // FullSimplify]
```

yields

> `True`

We define

```
test[a_] := 
 Integrate[
  E^(-2 I x) (Log[Sqrt[Cos[a - x]^2]] + 
     1/2 I π Sign[Cos[a - x]]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Subsequently we calculate

```
Table[test[index], {index, 0, 4}] // FullSimplify // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{55.2884, {π, E^(-2 I) π, E^(-4 I) π, E^(-6 I) π,  E^(-8 I) π}}`

In order to do some experimental bootstrap

```
FindSequenceFunction[{π, E^(-2 I) π, E^(-4 I) π, 
   E^(-6 I) π, E^(-8 I) π}, a + 1] // FullSimplify
```

> `E^(-2 I a) π`

And now we check against some higher values of `a` outside the pool that we used to bootstrap the answer.

Done! Now, someone give me a cookie

Answer (score 6):

With a little assistance for Mathematica v12.2 the integral is evaluated

Integrand is 2Pi periodic, we can transform `x-a->u`

```
E^(\[Minus]2 (  a) I) Integrate[E^(\[Minus]2 u I) (Log[Abs[Cos[u]]] + Pi I/2Sign[Cos[u]]), {u, 0,2 Pi}]
(*E^(-2 I a) \[Pi]*)
```

Comment: (+1) an excellent observation!

Comment: Perhaps you could add that ``Integrate`InverseIntegrate[stuff]`` fails in this case. This would be relevant, since ``Integrate`InverseIntegrate[stuff]`` attempts to perform the integration by various substitutions

Comment: @bmf Mathematica v12.2 evaluates without any message

Comment: If you mean the command that you wrote in the answer, I agree. This command runs smoothly in v13.2 as well. All, I meant is that ``Integrate`InverseIntegrate[original integral]`` does not return a result. I mean without your observation, just trying to automate the substitutions in Mathematica directly. That's all

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica 13.3.1 on Windows 10 does it:

```
Integrate[E^(\[Minus]2 x I) (Log[RealAbs[Cos[x \[Minus] a]]] + 
Pi I/2 Sign[Cos[x \[Minus] a]]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
Assumptions -> a >= 0 && a < 2*Pi] // ComplexExpand
```

> `Piecewise[{{Pi*Cos[2*a] - I*Pi*Sin[2*a], a > (3*Pi)/2 || a < Pi/2},  {(I*Cos[2*a] + 2*Pi*Cos[2*a] + 2*Arg[1 + E^((2*I)*a)]*Cos[2*a] +  I*Cos[2*a]^2 - Pi*Cos[2*a]^2 + I*Cos[2*a]*Log[4] -  I*Cos[2*a]^2*Log[Cos[a]^2] - I*Cos[2*a]* Log[(1 + Cos[2*a])^2 + Sin[2*a]^2] + Sin[2*a] -  (2*I)*Pi*Sin[2*a] - (2*I)*Arg[1 + E^((2*I)*a)]*Sin[2*a] +  Log[4]*Sin[2*a] - Log[(1 + Cos[2*a])^2 + Sin[2*a]^2]*Sin[2*a] +  I*Sin[2*a]^2 - Pi*Sin[2*a]^2 - I*Log[Cos[a]^2]*Sin[2*a]^2)/4,  a == (3*Pi)/2}, {(I*Cos[2*a] + 4*Pi*Cos[2*a] +  2*Arg[1 + E^((2*I)*a)]*Cos[2*a] + I*Cos[2*a]^2 + Pi*Cos[2*a]^2 +  2*Arg[Cos[a]]*Cos[2*a]^2 + I*Cos[2*a]*Log[4] -  I*Cos[2*a]^2*Log[Cos[a]^2] - I*Cos[2*a]* Log[(1 + Cos[2*a])^2 + Sin[2*a]^2] + Sin[2*a] -  (4*I)*Pi*Sin[2*a] - (2*I)*Arg[1 + E^((2*I)*a)]*Sin[2*a] +  Log[4]*Sin[2*a] - Log[(1 + Cos[2*a])^2 + Sin[2*a]^2]*Sin[2*a] +  I*Sin[2*a]^2 + Pi*Sin[2*a]^2 + 2*Arg[Cos[a]]*Sin[2*a]^2 -  I*Log[Cos[a]^2]*Sin[2*a]^2)/4, a == Pi/2}},  (3*Pi*Cos[2*a] - Pi*Cos[2*a]^2 + 2*Pi*Cos[a]^2*Cos[2*a]^2 -  (2*I)*Pi*Cos[a]*Cos[2*a]^2*Sin[a] - (3*I)*Pi*Sin[2*a] -  Pi*Sin[2*a]^2 + 2*Pi*Cos[a]^2*Sin[2*a]^2 -  (2*I)*Pi*Cos[a]*Sin[a]*Sin[2*a]^2)/4]`

It's simpler to consider the exceptional cases separately, for example,

```
Integrate[E^(\[Minus]2 x I) (Log[RealAbs[Cos[x\[Minus]a]]]+Pi I/2 Sign[Cos[x\[Minus]a]])/.a->3*Pi/2,{x,0,2 Pi}]
```

> `-Pi`

than to simplify the general case:

```
FullSimplify[(3*Pi*Cos[2*a]-Pi*Cos[2*a]^2+2*Pi*Cos[a]^2*Cos[2*a]^2-(2*I)*Pi*Cos[a]*Cos[2*a]^2*Sin[a]-(3*I)*Pi*Sin[2*a]-Pi*Sin[2*a]^2+2*Pi*Cos[a]^2*Sin[2*a]^2-(2*I)*Pi*Cos[a]*Sin[a]*Sin[2*a]^2)/4]
```

> `E^(-2 I a) \[Pi]`

Comment: The result of `Integrate[
  E^(\[Minus]2 x I) (Log[RealAbs[Cos[x \[Minus] a]]] + 
     Pi I/2 Sign[Cos[x \[Minus] a]]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> a >= -5 && a < 10] // ComplexExpand` is similar.